# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/util/dao/orm/CustomSQLUtil

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have added the jar named util-java.jar containing the above mentioned file into the build .gradle file. At compile time there is no error. But on executing the project I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Please tell me how to eradicate this problem. My build.gradle is as follows:-

```
dependencies {
    compile group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
    compile project(":modules:customuser:customuser-api")

    compile group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'portal-kernel', version: '5.2.3'
    runtime group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'portal-kernel', version: '5.2.3'



    compile group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'util-java', version: '6.2.4'
    runtime group: 'com.liferay.portal', name: 'util-java', version: '6.2.4'
}
```

Comment: Does your bundle import `com.liferay.util.dao.orm` package?

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.custom.sql", version: "1.0.5"

Should help you.

Answer (score 0):

This a version issue, change

```
compile group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
```

to

```
compile group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.5.0"
```